# Would adding abstractions over sets be inconsistent or otherwise increase the consistency strength?

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

Is adding abstractions (in the below mentioned manner) over $ZFC$ inconsistent? if not then does it result in increment of consistency strength?

The idea is to add a new primitive binary relation "*is abstracted from*", denoted as: $``\curvearrowleft"$, to the language of set theory (first order logic with equality and membership) and we add the following extensionality and comprehension axioms for abstractions.

1. Extensional abstractions: $\forall \zeta \eta \ [\forall x (\zeta \curvearrowleft x \leftrightarrow \eta \curvearrowleft x) \to \zeta=\eta]$

In English: Abstractions abstracted from the same objects are identical.

2. Abstracting scheme: If $R$ is a binary relation symbol defined after a formula in the language of set theory that doesn't use the symbol $``\zeta"$, then:

$ R \text{ is equivalence relation } \to \forall x \ \exists \zeta \ \forall y (\zeta \curvearrowleft y \leftrightarrow y \ R \ x)$

is an axiom.

So to re-iterate my questions:

> 1. Is the above addition on top of $ZFC$ consistent?
> 2. If Yes, would it increase the consistency strenght or not?
> 3. if we unleash the abstracting schema for abstractions to come from any equivalence relation, i.e. just remove the restriction to language of set theory; would that result in an inconsistent theory?

Comment: My gut feeling is it would do nothing to consistency strength because there's not really any interaction with with $\in$. I don't see how you'd be able to prove any $\in$-sentences you couldn't prove before.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, I'm particularly suspicious of 3. I think it might lead to an inconsistency?

Comment: All the weakened version of 2 says, in conjunction with 1, is that a thing exists for every one-parameter definable class, right? And $\curvearrowleft$ can't appear in $R$? A model of this should be trivial to cook up from a model of the set theory.